# Check engine light 2005 Toyota Camry

Tags: toyota, cel, p1135

I am getting a P1135 code on my 2005 Toyota Camry.I have replaced the A/F sensor first with a Bosch then with a Denso. I am still getting the same trouble code almost immediately after starting the car up. I checked the connector for power at the connector and I have power at the lower right male connector. What is my next step?

Comment: What size engine?

Comment: Also you list the code as a P1135 which is an O2 Sensor code, but you said you replaced the Air Flow sensor. Also P1135 doesn't come up as a valid code for this make, model, year.

Comment: if you get an engine code, don't just assume the sensor is bad, maybe it's working fine but the sensory input (emissions in this case) is what trips the threshold.

Comment: no, air flow is measure by a MAF sensor. an A/F sensor is the Air/fuel sensor. different from an O2 sensor, but serves the same purpose. i think a p1135 is usually a heater circuit code. could be a wiring issue or bad/wrong sensor. double check the part number on the new sensor

Answer (score 1):

### [`P1135`](http://engine-codes.com/p1135_toyota.html): AFR Sensor Heater Circuit Malfunction Bank 1 Sensor 1

As discovered, the malfunction doesn't necessarily have to be in the sensor itself.

### Possible causes for a P1135 code include:

- <strike>Faulty Air-Fuel Ratio (A/F) Sensor Bank 1 Sensor 1</strike> (already ruled out by replacement)
- Air-Fuel Ratio (A/F) Sensor Bank 1 Sensor 1 harness is open or shorted
- Air-Fuel Ratio (A/F) Sensor Bank 1 Sensor 1 circuit poor electrical connection
- Faulty Engine Control Module (ECM)

---

A faulty ECM is possible, but not probable, so the CEL is likely due to a break in the heater circuit which you will need to trace.

A very nice video by [Schrodinger's Box](http://youtu.be/rWoEIEAql2I) shows him diagnose a similar problem on a Nissan Maxima.

Comment: BAM ------- consider this question answered!